# What was fpmake.pp used and is it still used?

Tags: freepascal, fpc, fpmake

I've used it once, not very well since I found hard to get by some decent examples/docs but it was a nice way of getting an environment done.

Is it still a standard or as it been abandoned?

Where could I find a beginner's  how-to and also an advanced one so I can grow on usage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was supposed to be the successor to Makefile.fpc/Makefile combo's, but the person that made it ran out of steam/time halfway through the introduction.

Comment: Like always our very good FPC expert to the rescue :) Thanks Marco

Comment: Just a simple question: Has anyone taken any interest on continuing the devel? Is all the source within a normal dist, so I can go through it? And, again, many thanks Marco